How to track data from database to TImgView32/TImage32 in Delphi 12?
Each record of my database can have more than one photo. The TImage32/TImgView32 components are dynamically created in a TGridPanel. It's like a little image gallery or preview. If you click on an image I need to know the id and filepath of the image for editing. The Comboxbox for example has an AddObject method, but a TImage32 component has not.
How can I track the data? Thanks for help!
Kind regards

No idea? Do you need more details?
